# Find nth tetrahedic number

Tags: javascript, math, geometry

```js
function tetra(n) {
  let triangle = [1, ];
  for (let i = 2; i < n - 1; i++) {
    triangle.push(i + triangle[i - 2]);
  }
  let somma = 0;
  for (let j = 0; j < triangle.length; j++) {
    somma = somma + triangle[j];
  }
  return somma;
}

console.log(tetra(1));
console.log(tetra(3));
console.log(tetra(5));
```

The goal of this function is to find the nth tetrahedric number, but it returns always one, without adding items in the array of the triangular numbers. Can somebody write this to me? Thanks for your help :)

Comment: It doesn't always return `1` for me. I don't see how it could always return `1` as written or not do what the code says to do.

Comment: It starts working correctly when it gets to `tetra(3)`, except it's off by 2.

Comment: So `tetra(3)` returns what `tetra(1)` should return, `tetra(4)` returns the expected `tetra(2)`, and so on.

Comment: Simpler way:  `return n*(n+1)*(n+2)/6;`

Comment: Looks like you have made a good start. To debug, here are 2 ideas. (1) Looks like `triangle` is important. Print out the value of `triangle` after adding another row to it. Does `triangle` look like what you expect? (2) Instead of modifying `triangle` by pushing stuff onto it, try creating a new triangle, and print the old and new triangles, and then assign `triangle  = triangle_new`. Generally it's easier to understand what is going on by working with whole things rather than incremental changes in place. These are just a couple of general strategies to help you figure out what's going on.